# Detect a file with two arbitrary characters along a file path and move it to another file path in R

Tags: r, directory, character, gsub

I am looking to copy a file along a path and move it to another location via `file.copy()` in R.

Say, the file exists here:

`C:/Folder1/Folder2/Some_file_10.xlsx`

And I want to move it here:

`C:/Folder1/AnotherFolder/Some_file_10.xlsx`

The file name is `Some_file_10.xlsx`. The `10` in the file name is arbitrary and will change when new code is run, but it will always be two numeric digits. How can I use `file.copy()`, `paste()`, and something type of character matching package to both detect `Some_file_10` and move it with the same name, like so:

```
file.copy(from = paste0("C:/Folder1/Folder2/Some_file_",
                        function(), 
                        ".xlsx"),
          to = paste0("C:/Folder1/AnotherFolder/Some_file_",
                       function(),
                       ".xlsx))
```

An additional note: There will be no other files with the same starting characters of `Some_file_` along this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sys.glob to find the file. For the `to=` argument we only need to specify the directory.

```
file.copy(from = Sys.glob("C:/Folder1/Folder2/Some_file_*.xlsx"),
          to = "C:/Folder1/AnotherFolder")
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you change the name within `to=` if need be?

Comment: The question specified that they are the same but to= can specify the entire path including the filename if you want to change it.